# How to dynamically add option to select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently adding rows to an HTML table and have three linked select statements that are linked to the values in all rows. When I change the select value in the second row, the select values in the remaining rows also change together. I would like to know how to have independent values for each row.

Unfortunately, i cannot modify the addRow() function.

Please help me...

```js
function random_function(e) {

  if (e.value === "DO") {
    var arr = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Seal(1)", "Seal(2)"];
    var list = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Stamp(1)", "Stamp(2)", "Etc(1)", "Etc(2)"];
  } else if (e.value === "DL") {
    var arr = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Seal"];
    var list = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Stamp", "Hello(1)", "Hello(2)"];
  } else if (e.value === "DM") {
    var arr = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Seal"];
    var list = ["-- Select --", "NO", "Stamp", "Hello(1)", "Hello(2)"];
  }

  $(e).parent().parent().parent().find("tr#sealing").find("td.output").find("select.outputa option").remove();
  $(e).parent().parent().parent().find("tr#stamping").find("td.outputing").find("select.stamped option").remove();

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(e).parent().parent().parent().find("tr#sealing").find("td.output").find("select.outputa").append("<option value='" + arr[i] + "'>" + arr[i] + "</option>");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $(e).parent().parent().parent().find("tr#stamping").find("td.outputing").find("select.stamped").append("<option value='" + list[i] + "'>" + list[i] + "</option>");
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <td colspan="7">
    <select data-type="mField" name="company" id="company" data-element-type="sel_d_v" onchange="random_function(this)">
      <option value="">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="DO">DO</option>
      <option value="DL">DL</option>
      <option value="DM">DM</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="sealing">
  <th>SEAL</th>
  <td class="output" colspan="3">
    <select class="outputa" name="seal" id="seal" data-type="mField" data-element-type="sel_d_v" style="width:90%;" onchange="sealHidden_function(this)">
      <option>-- Select --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="sealHidden" data-type="mField" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ doc.BODY_CONTEXT.sealHidden }}" hidden="hidden" />
  </td>
  <th>Num</th>
  <td colspan="3">
    <input type="text" id="seal1" data-type="mField" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ doc.BODY_CONTEXT.seal1 }}" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="stamping">
  <th>STAMP</th>
  <td class="outputing" colspan="3">
    <select class="stamped" data-type="mField" data-element-type="sel_d_v" name="stamp" id="stamp" style="width:90%;" onchange="stampHidden_function(this)">
      <option>-- Select --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="stampHidden" data-type="mField" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ doc.BODY_CONTEXT.stampHidden }}" hidden="hidden" />
  </td>
  <th>Num</th>
  <td colspan="3">
    <input type="text" id="seal2" data-type="mField" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ doc.BODY_CONTEXT.seal2 }}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Soooo you have a bunch of jQuery up there. Are you asking how to convert that code?

Comment: There is no addRow function. Please see [ask], then revise to make your specific question more clear.

Comment: FYI, something like `.parent().parent().parent().find("tr#sealing")` is completely unnecessary since any ID must be unique. Just use `('#sealing')...`.

Comment: Unfortunately, if it is not written in this way, the select values of the function cannot be called..

Comment: I seriously doubt that's true. At any  rate your question needs improvement.